# How can i get two result set array in single array without calling function again?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Here I fire two queries by calling single function..

```
$category  = [];
$sub_category = [];

$query_parent_category = "select name from category where parent_id = 0";
$query_child_category="select name from category where parent_id = 1";
$category = $this->runSelectQuery($query_parent_categoty);
$sub_category = $this->runSelectQuery($query_child_categoty);

return array($category,$sub_category);
```

function `runSelectQuery` is like...

```
 public function runSelectQuery($sql) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);
        $listinfdata = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $listinfdata[] = $row;
        }

        return $listinfdata;
    }
```

but it is not lool optimize.. i need that two array in single function call .. which means  `$category[]` and `$sub_category[]` in single array .. result like to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => MEN
            [subcat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Jeans
                    [1] => Shirts
                    [2] => T-shirts
                    [3] => Chinos
                    [4] => Blazers
                    [5] => Night Wear
                )

        )
)
```

and so on ..

Comment: wait are you merging them? if yes `select name from category where parent_id in (0, 1)`

Comment: table name category with id as primary key ,name as varchar(255) and parent_id as int (11)..it contains some data based on that i get "name"

Comment: (id name parent_id)     
(1 MEN 0),
(2 jeans 1),
(3 Shirts 1),
(4 T-shirts 1),
(5 Chinos 1),
(6 Blazers 1),
(7 Night Wear 1)
8 Women 0
9 KIDS 0
10 ACCESSORIES 0

Comment: no i want that one array from which i can access the both like MEN has sub category of ->> jeans,shirts and so on

Comment: could you make it more clear like by making a php array result for example

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => MEN
            [subcat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Jeans
                    [1] => Shirts
                    [2] => T-shirts
                    [3] => Chinos
                    [4] => Blazers
                    [5] => Night Wear
                )

        )12:23
)

Comment: i update in my question please look after it

Comment: does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: yes 100% solved thanks

Comment: don't forget to vote my question :D @Beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More Answer here...

How about if you have more than 1 parent category

like this

[image]

Use this query

```
SELECT `parent_category`.`id`, `parent_category`.`name` as `parent_category`, `child_category`.`name` as `child_category` FROM `category` `parent_category` join `category` `child_category` on `parent_category`.`id` = `child_category`.`parent_id`
```

This query produce result like this

[image]

To group your category first

declare a variable which contains the parent_id of your `$row`

```
$prev_parent = null;
```

let it be as null

then

in while loop

Create 3 condition(s)

First Condition: check if `$prev_parent` is null then create your first category

```
if ($prev_parent == null) {
    $prev_parent = $row['id'];
    $listinfdata[] = array(
        'name' => $row['parent_category'],
        'subcat' => array($row['child_category'])
    );
}
```

This condition would create something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'Parent Category 1'
            [subcat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'Child Category 1'
                )
        )
);
```

Second Condition: check if `$row['id']` or parent_id is same as $prev_parent which your your previous parent id category

If that match to this condition just insert the subcategory to the latest subcategories of the latest parent category

```
`sizeof($listinfdata)-1` since array always started at index 0
```

Do this

```
$prev_parent = $row['id'];
$listinfdata[sizeof($listinfdata)-1]['subcat'][] = $row['child_category'];
```

This condition would create something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'Parent Category 1'
            [subcat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'Child Category 1',
                    [1] => 'Child Category 2'
                )
        )
);
```

Last Condition `else` means if `$prev_parent` is not empty but the current parent_category is not same to the 
`$prev_parent` insert another parent category with it's first sub category

```
$prev_parent = $row['id'];
$listinfdata[] = array(
    'name' => $row['parent_category'],
    'subcat' => array($row['child_category'])
);
```

This condition would create something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'Parent Category 1'
            [subcat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'Child Category 1',
                    [1] => 'Child Category 2'
                )
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'Parent Category 2'
            [subcat] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 'Child Category 1',
                )
        )
);
```

So your code would be like this

```
<?php

    $category  = [];
    $sub_category = [];
    $query_category = "SELECT `parent_category`.`id`, `parent_category`.`name` as `parent_category`, `child_category`.`name` as `child_category` FROM `category` `parent_category` join `category` `child_category` on `parent_category`.`id` = `child_category`.`parent_id`";

    $sub_category = $this->runSelectQuery($query_category);

    return array($sub_category);


function `runSelectQuery` is like...

public function runSelectQuery($sql) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);
    $listinfdata = array();

    $prev_parent = null;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $category = null;
        if ($prev_parent == null) {
            $prev_parent = $row['id'];
            $listinfdata[] = array(
                'name' => $row['parent_category'],
                'subcat' => array($row['child_category'])
            );
        } else if ($row['id'] == $prev_parent) {
            $prev_parent = $row['id'];
            $listinfdata[sizeof($listinfdata)-1]['subcat'][] = $row['child_category'];
        } else {
            $prev_parent = $row['id'];
            $listinfdata[] = array(
                'name' => $row['parent_category'],
                'subcat' => array($row['child_category'])
            );
        }
    }

    return $listinfdata;
}
```

And the result is like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this simply you could modify your query by using "OR" operator.

```
$category  = [];
$query_parent_categoty = "select name from category where parent_id = 0 OR parent_id = 1";
$category = $this->runSelectQuery($query_parent_categoty);
 return array($category);
```

Comment: better use `parent_id IN(0, 1)` use it's much faster than `OR`

Comment: you are right but it does not match with my requirement.. i want menu and submenu implementation by using my two query

Answer (score 0):

Just like @beginner commented, using `IN` is better than `OR`

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM category WHERE parent_id IN (0,1)";
$category = $this->runSelectQuery($query);
```

Comment: i explain you by example  **$menu = [
                ["name" => "home",
                "link" => "home.php",
                "sub_menu" => [
                        ["name" => "home1",
                        "link" => "home.php",

                    ],
                    ["name" => "home2",
                        "link" => "home.php",

                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]; ** in this menu variable "sub-menu" is there in wich i want to store the result of my second query  **$query_child_categoty="select name from category where parent_id = 1";**